# Is there a c# Webcam/Video WPF component that can help me capture video?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, wpf-controls, video-capture

I am looking for a component for WPF application that will can work with webcams and video input devices, I need it to be able to:

1. Capture video
2. Capture still image
3. Work with Webcams

I am open to both **open source** and **commercial** libraries

Thanks

EDIT: I am currently using [MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Aforge .NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) is a free library for .net framework, it helps you capture vieos from webcam and process images within the video.

Answer (score 0):

[DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) is an option too.